# Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(CharacterList)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to test my React "supersquadapp" and getting the following error.

Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(CharacterList)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(CharacterList)".

characterlist.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CharacterList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('this.props', this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>characters</h4>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        characters: state.characters
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CharacterList);
```

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CharacterList from './CharacterList';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>SUPER SQUAD</h2>
                <CharacterList />
            </div>
        )
    }
} 
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './Components/App';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import rootReducers from './reducers';
import { addCharacterById } from './actions';


const store = createStore(rootReducers);
console.log(store.getState());
store.subscribe(() => console.log('store',store.getState()))
store.dispatch(addCharacterById(3));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider>
        <App />
     </Provider>
    ,document.getElementById('root')
)
```

character.js(in reducers folder)

```
import characters_json from '../Data/characters.json';
import { ADD_CHARACTER } from '../actions';

function characters(state = characters_json, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_CHARACTER:
        let characters = state.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
        return characters;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default characters;
```

heroes.js(reducers folder)

```
import { ADD_CHARACTER } from '../actions';
import {createCharacter} from './helper';

function heroes(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_CHARACTER:
        let heroes = [...state, createCharacter(action.id)];
        return heroes;
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default heroes;
```

helper.js(reducers folder)

```
import characters_json from '../Data/characters.json';

export function createCharacter(id) {
    let character = characters_json.find(c => c.id === id);
    return character;
}
```

index.js(reducers folder)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import characters from './characters_reducer';
import heroes from './heroes_reducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    characters,
    heroes
})
export default rootReducer;
```

index.js(action folder)

```
export const ADD_CHARACTER = 'ADD_CHARACTER';

export function addCharacterById(id) {
    const action = {
        type:ADD_CHARACTER,
        id
    }
    return action;
}
```

The above error occurred in the  component:

in Connect(CharacterList) (at App.js:9)

in div (at App.js:7)

in App (at index.js:19)

in Provider (at index.js:18)

please help me...?

Comment: Have you tried `<Provider store={store}>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must pass the store instance to Provider...

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
     </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's question though, since they are testing. I don't believe this answers that question?

Comment: Well I guess if that implied unit testing it did so very vaguely! I read as manually testing in a browser seeing as that was a fundamental error in the application itself that would cause it to happen anyway, and there was no unit test code at all

Answer (score 15):

If you are running a test and you have something like alechill's answer, you'd need this to change in the test, for example:

```
let mockedStore = configureStore([])({});
test('some test', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent foo="bar" />, {
    context: { store: mockedStore },
    childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.object.isRequired }
  });
  expect(.... your tests here);
});
```

Comment: true that, although I don't think unit tests were what the Q was about, +1'ed for extra info, ta!