# React-Redux Provider not working for me. How i solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The provider does not send the store to the component and I get an error

```
 Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
```

This is the code:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
        ,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: Showing the relevant imports, as well as the versions of redux and react-redux used, could help.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to import Provider with "react-redux / lib / components / Provider" not with "react-redux" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

look this. may be helped for you.

[Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(CharacterList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652627/either-wrap-the-root-component-in-a-provider-or-explicitly-pass-store-as-a)
and
[Could not find "store", even if the root is wrapped in Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566060/could-not-find-store-even-if-the-root-is-wrapped-in-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue, I noticed my import for Provider was incorrect. This solved my issue!

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'